# Node Selenium ChromeDriver Ubuntu NoSuchSessionError: This driver instance does not have a valid session ID

Tags: node.js, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hey I am trying to start a Selenium instance on

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04 64bit / Linux 4.4.0-36-generic
- Node: v6.5.0
- NPM: 3.10.3
- "chromedriver": "^2.23.1",
- "selenium-webdriver": "^3.0.0-beta-2",

I keep receiving this error.

```
/var/www/node-bin/portlight-orders/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:432
        throw new error.NoSuchSessionError(
        ^

NoSuchSessionError: This driver instance does not have a valid session ID (did you call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used.
    at WebDriverError (/var/www/node-bin/portlight-orders/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:5)
    at NoSuchSessionError (/var/www/node-bin/portlight-orders/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:122:5)
    at checkHasNotQuit (/var/www/node-bin/portlight-orders/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:432:15)
    at Driver.schedule (/var/www/node-bin/portlight-orders/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:393:5)
    at Driver.quit (/var/www/node-bin/portlight-orders/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:480:23)
    at exitHandler (/var/www/node-bin/portlight-orders/api/services/Selenium.js:12:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at process._fatalException (bootstrap_node.js:296:26)
```

In glances I see that chromedriver is running
http://image.prntscr.com/image/dfc336afbf6f46d59017b4135e9547c3.png
[image]

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();

module.exports = driver;

function exitHandler(options, err) {
    driver.quit()
}

//do something when app is closing
process.on('exit', exitHandler.bind(null,{cleanup:true}));

//catches ctrl+c event
process.on('SIGINT', exitHandler.bind(null, {exit:true}));

//catches uncaught exceptions
process.on('uncaughtException', exitHandler.bind(null, {exit:true}));
```

Answer (score -1):

Before using any driver instance check whether that driver session is active or not here we have two cases
1. session id is present
 if session id present then we can go further
2. session id doesn't exist
so we can't go further either stop